# why is this rvalue constexpr constructor invoked at runtime?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Why would the following code treat the usage of class A as constexpr for the first two cases but not for the third case? I've tried this with various versions of gcc from 4.9 to 7.1 and experience the same behavior each time. What am I missing here?

```
template <std::size_t N> struct B{};

class A
{
public:
    constexpr A(std::size_t value):value_(value){}
    std::size_t const value_;
};


std::int32_t main
(
    std::int32_t,
    char const **
)
{
    A a(1);           // expected - constructor not invoked at run time
    B<A(1).value_> b; // expected - compiles so clearly constexpr
    A(1);             // *** unexpected *** - invokes the constructor at run time, why?
    return 0;
}
```

**updated with a more comprehensive example**

```
template <std::size_t N> 
struct B
{
    constexpr std::size_t dont_optimize_me_out
    (
    )
    {
        return 0;
    }
};


constexpr std::size_t some_hash
(
    char const *,
    std::size_t
)
{
    return 0;
}


class hashed_id
{
public:

    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr hashed_id
    (
        char const (&input)[N]
    ):
        value_(some_hash(input, N - 1))
    {
    }

    constexpr hashed_id
    (
        std::size_t value
    ):
        value_(value)
    {
    }

    constexpr std::size_t get_value
    (
    )
    {
        return value_;
    }

private:

    std::size_t const value_;
};


class A
{
public:

    constexpr A
    (
        hashed_id id
    ):
        id_(id)
    {
    }

    constexpr hashed_id get_id
    (
    )
    {
        return id_;
    }

    constexpr std::size_t dont_optimize_me_out
    (
    )
    {
        return id_.get_value();
    }

private:

    hashed_id const id_;
};


int main
(
    int,
    char const **
)
{
    std::size_t k = 0;

    A a("foo"); // expected - constructor not invoked at run time
    k += a.dont_optimize_me_out();

    B<A("foo").dont_optimize_me_out()> b; // expected - compiles so clearly constexpr
    k += b.dont_optimize_me_out();

    k += A("foo").dont_optimize_me_out(); // *** unexpected *** - invokes the constructor (and hash function) at run time, why?

    std::cout << k << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [OT] That is an interesting signature for `main`.  Not sure if it violates the standard or not since `int` does not have to be the same as `int32_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It is a violation. 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] states, that `main` *"shall have a declared return type of type `int`"*.

Comment: @IInspectable Does that mean it is illegal in all cases or just when `int32_t `is not `int`?  Like is `using bar = int; bar main() {}` non-standard?

Comment: @NathanOliver: It says *"**declared** return type of type `int`"*, so I guess that anything but `int` is a violation.

Comment: @IInspectable Makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `A a(1);` invoking constructor at run time?

Comment: @Sklert Good catch. I reviewed my question numerous times and somehow I still managed to miss the error in the comment for A a(1);!  I've updated the comment to match what I had described in the wording of my question. Specifically, A a(1); does NOT invoke the constructor at run time.

Comment: I don't know how it could create and discard a temporary object in compile time. Either it can do so at runtime, or it can optimize it away and never call it. What are the optimization settings?

Comment: @KennyOstrom The optimization setting is -O3. The example I posted is, obviously, simpler than my actual real world case. What is posted is the the just simplest way to reproduce the behavior so, in reality, the compiler isn't going to optimize anything away. I see you're point though in that perhaps I've simplified the example so much that, while it does embody the issue, it has been pruned to the point where you can't infer what I've already ruled out. I will update the example to make my usage case clearer as well.

Comment: My real point was: it can't be done at compile time because it would have been nonsensical/paradoxical to create and discard a temporary runtime object ... at compile time. Update seems to fix that at first glance, but can't look in detail right now.

Comment: I have reproduced on gcc 8.5, with a gdb breakpoint in A::A, but I don't have a good answer. It is a temporary value, but everything up until size_t is constexpr, so I would have expected it to compile as if you had just put a constant integer value there. Unless the instance of class hashed_id blocks that. Hmm.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks for laking the time to investigate. Whatever the reason, it certainly is subtle since the statement that fails to be constexpr is the very same one used as a template argument in the prior statement.